# Rails_admin, change values of enum field depending of association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-admin

I have four models: `Shop`, `Item`, `Category`, `SubCategory`

`Shops` has  `has_and_belongs_to_many` association with `Category` and `SubCategory`.

`Shops` has `has_many` association with `Items`.

`Category` has `has_many` association with `SubCategories`.

Both `Category` and `SubCategory` has_many `Items`.

When I create `Shop` I can choose a lot of Categories and SubCategories.

When I try to create `Item`, `rails_admin` creates select boxes for Categories and SubCategories. However, there is problem. **It makes me to choose from ALL categories and subcategories**.

I want to be able to select only categories and subcategories which are belong to my selected shop.

Is it possible in rails_admin to change select enums values depending on other models associations?

Code for `Category`

```
class Category
    include Mongoid::Document
    has_many :sub_categories, inverse_of: :category
    has_many :items

    accepts_nested_attributes_for :sub_categories
end
```

Code for `SubCategory`

```
class SubCategory
    include Mongoid::Document
    has_many :items
    belongs_to :category, inverse_of: :sub_categories
end
```

Code for `Shop`

```
class Shop
    include Mongoid::Document
    has_many :items, dependent: :destroy, inverse_of: :shop
    has_and_belongs_to_many :categories, inverse_of: nil
    has_and_belongs_to_many :sub_categories, inverse_of: nil
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :items
end
```

Code for `Item`

```
class Item
    include Mongoid::Document
    belongs_to :shop, inverse_of: :items
    belongs_to :category
    belongs_to :sub_category
end
```

**============================ Possible solution =======================**

Because there is one sided `has_and_belongs_to_many` assocation between `Shop` and `Category`,  That means `Shop` stores array of ids of `Categories`.

Also my models are **Mongoid Documents**, which means that I can not use joins.

In my `Item edit` action I have added this code:

```
field :category do
    associated_collection_cache_all false
    associated_collection_scope do
       item = bindings[:object]
      shop = item.shop
      Proc.new { |scope|
        scope = scope.where(id: {"$in" => shop.category_ids.map(&:to_s)}) if item.present?
      }
    end
end
```

Now it allows me to choose Categories by Shops Categories. However, there is a problem that I can not use this on `create` action

Answer (score 2, accepted):

rails_admin supports scoped associations. See:

https://github.com/sferik/rails_admin/wiki/Associations-scoping

For example:

```
config.model Item do
  field :category do
    associated_collection_cache_all false  
    associated_collection_scope do
      item = bindings[:object]
      Proc.new { |scope|
        scope = scope.joins(:shops).where(shops: {id: item.shop_id}) if item.present?
      }
    end
  end
end
```

Note the warning that "bindings[:object] can be null for new parent records!". You may have to save the Item before the scope takes effect. In the past I've added a conditional to the active_admin form so the scoped field only shows up once the record is saved.

Comment: Could you add the `Item`, `Shop` and `Category` associations to your question as code? Do items have a category that's separate from their shop's category?

Comment: Edited my answer, but (sorry about this), my syntax for the join may not be right and I can't easily test it. Corrections welcome, hope this gives you the idea.

Comment: I'm surprised you needed to map `to_s`, but yeah, I can't think of a way to scope on create until the `item` is saved with a `shop_id`.

Comment: You are right. It worked without mapping `to_s`. We can't change values of fields dynamically on views, depending on chosen values in `rails_admin`, are we?

Comment: Best I can tell you have to handle it in the view: either require the user to 'save and edit' before exposing the category field, or populate the dropdown with an ajax request after the user selects  a shop. Neither is especially pretty. The first is easier but clunky UX.

Comment: I think this answer is valid only if `shop_id` is read-only in the edit form. If it's editable, then changing shop in the edit form won't take place in categories as it will still show the old shop list. Ref https://github.com/sferik/rails_admin/wiki/Associations-scoping

"bindings[:object] can be null for new parent records! Also note that the scope takes in to account the saved version of the record, not considering any unsaved changes you may have made in the edit form. If you change the team's league, you'll still see the players from the old league until you save."